# Do milliseconds have any effect when VLCJ is playing a video segment?

Tags: java, vlc, libvlc, vlcj

Does specifying milliseconds in addition to seconds have any effect when VLCJ is playing segment of a video? Given case scenario:

```
 mediaPlayer.playMedia("C://video.avi", ":start-time=50", ":stop-time=55");
```

Is it possible to specify milliseconds as well (in addition to seconds), and won't they just be ignored? I need more precision when playing particular video segments.

Answer (score 0):

That's a matter for VLC really, not vlcj.

You specify fractions of a second like this:

```
:start-time=50.5
```

Comment: Thanks. What is the max precision? Is it one tenth of a second maximum (as per your example) or it could be more granular, say actual milliseconds?

Comment: I even looked for the answer in VLC command line help:
https://wiki.videolan.org/VLC_command-line_help
It does not say anything about milliseconds. So just wondering if actual milliseconds (as in 50.543 for instance) have any effect or it is just tenths of seconds that are honored

Comment: As a comparison, try using mediaPlayer.setTime(ms), that will show you how granular you can be. IIRC, you can *not* get reliable millisecond precision.

Comment: Thanks @caprica. Your answers were really helpful. I would vote them up, but I just don't have enough of the reputation score yet.